# Remove 'Running Header' from achemso manuscript

Tags: achemso

I'm using the recommended package [achemso](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/achemso?lang=en) in the preparation of an ACS manuscript. The class puts a running header on the title page, which the editors want me to remove. The running header is set in the optional title argument. Unfortunately, if no optional argument is given, the running header will be equal to the title. If it is filled with a blank space as in the code below, the bold text 'Running Header' still appears.

```
\documentclass[journal=bichaw]{achemso}
\author{Mr. Mad Cat}
\title[ ]{Mouse House}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to remove the running header without modifying the class? If not, what would be a good/safe change to the class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is printed as historically authors have been asked to provide a running header by *Biochemistry*. The text can be disabled using

```
\makeatletter
\def\acs@maketitle@extras@hook{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I'll check up on what the 'official' position is on whether this is still required:  I don't necessarily get told

Comment: Thank you - I have put it before `\begin{document}` and it works.